# How do I move the location of an xcodeproj file without breaking external build target?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.3

I have an Xcode project with a directory structure like this:

> MasterProjectDir/projectname.xcodeproj
>   MasterProjectDir/ProjectSubDir/whatever.c
>   MasterProjectDir/ProjectSubDir/etc.c
>   MasterProjectDir/ProjectSubDir/Makefile

My xcodeproj uses an external build target to point to the Makefile using these settings:

> Build Tool: /usr/bin/make
>   Arguments: $(ACTION)
>   Directory: ./ProjectSubDir

For various reasons, I need to change the project directory structure to look like this:

> MasterProjectDir/projectname.xcodeproj
>   MasterProjectDir/whatever.c
>   MasterProjectDir/etc.c
>   MasterProjectDir/Makefile

I copied the .xcodeproj file into the ProjectSubDir and the project somehow still knows where to look for the files (?!?! - this is odd because their location is set as "relative to group" and I've just moved the xcodeproj file). It won't build. I get the following error:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
>   Command /usr/bin/make failed with exit code 2

I could use a little help on this. There must be a setting I need to change somewhere.

Comment: Let me clarify: I need to put the xcodeprojfile in the same dir as the Makefile for my External Build Target without using an absolute path for the Directory location. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the Makefile was missing from the project references and the directory on the external build target needed to be set to . where the . represents the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove your code files from XCode and re add him all

1) cmd + 1

2) remove all Red files

3) Add file and choose your *.c files

Comment: None of the files are red. It seems to be having no problem finding the files. I can open them and look at them...